# I find it's easier to remember the words (in) this way

Tags: prepositions

> I put all the animals words together, and all the clothes words together, and so on. I find it's easier to remember the words **(in)** this way.

Should I use *in* before "this way" in the above sentence or it is optional?

Comment: The "in" is optional.  The sentence is fine either way.  When used as an adverb, "in this way" and "this way" are equivalent.

Comment: "animal words", because in your example *animal* is a modifier (the kind of words), not a noun.

Comment: I agree with user3169, but be careful with the word "clothes"; we use it as a plural noun, so do not take off the -s in this case. Or you could use "clothing," to eliminate any confusion :).